# Migrating from pagination to uib-pagination - how to set total-items?

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm currently updating a 3 year old project where I used an early version of Angular UI Bootstrap. Among other things I try to migrate `pagination` to `uib-pagination`, but even though I read the documentation and tried to search for it, I couldn't find an explanation for total-items explaining why it needs to be higher than the pages.

Here's what I had before:

```
 <pagination num-pages="player.rounds.length" current-page="selectedRound" class="pagination-centered" previous-text="Vorherige Runde" next-text="Nächste Runde" on-select-page="selectedRound=page"></pagination>
```

This is what I use now

```
<uib-pagination total-items="player.rounds.length*8" ng-model="selectedRound" class="pagination" previous-text="Vorherige Runde" next-text="Nächste Runde"></uib-pagination>
```

Can someone point me to or give me a good explanation of total-items? 
Why do I have to multiply it by 8 with `uib-pagination` to get a similar result compared with  `pagination`?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation is quite sparse, it took me a while to figure this out. The parameter `items-per-page` controls the items per page. By default  `itemsPerPage` is set to 10. The example in the `uib-pagination` documentation was confusing me, because the total-items are set to 64 which just means the first 6 pages have 10 items and the 7th page has only 4 items.

To get the same behaviour as with `pagination`, the `items-per-page` just need to be set to 1.